# What's solution for sending emails from python while gmail " the less secure apps " is not enabled anymore

Tags: python, email, smtp

I recently was using smtp library for sending emails from gmail account but recently it stopped working after research I found out the google can not let you enable the less secure app anymore . So is there any workaround this ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue using Gmail SMTP, you can set it up by setting an app password. An app password works like an alternate password for your account. It can only be used by the applications you share it with, so it’s more secure than sharing your primary password.

Here's how you can set it up: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Less secure apps (https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps) options is disabled.

We need to use apppasswords using following link.
https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/apppasswords

Note: 2-factor authentication needs to be enabled if not enabled already.

Use 16 digit code provided by google instead of password and which will work for authentication.

[image]